# How to make a complete backup of an Android device

Tags: backup

I am quite new to Android and
I would like to be able to make a complete backup of an Android smartphone storage so that I can restore everything in case I mess it up or it breaks. My plan is to buy another phone of exactly the same model and restore my image to it so that I get exactly the same system back as the old one was at the time of the backup.

I have some experience doing this with a laptop. In this case I boot the laptop using an external USB stick with a live Linux distribution (let's say the USB stick is `/dev/sdb` after boot), attach an external drive (seen as `/dev/sdc`) that is larger than my laptop's internal disk (`/dev/sda`). From the live system I then do something like:

```
# mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
# dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/sda.img
# umount /mnt
# reboot
```

The procedure for restoring the image is similar.

I have found some guides and questions on how to do this on Android but most of them show how to backup user files or individual partitions, which is not what I want.

I illustrate my questions with reference to [this guide](https://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-backup-your-android-phones-boot-recovery-and-system-partition-images/) (from which I would prefer the adb + dd method, because it does not require to install additional software).

**Question 1** The guide says that I should root the device: why is this needed?

**Question 2** The guide shows how to make images of individual partitions but I would like to make an image of the whole system device with something like

```
dd if=/dev/mtd of=...
```

Would this work at all? Since I have to boot the device in order to connect to it with adb, will one or more partitions be mounted? Of course, I do not want this: all filesystems should be unmounted while I perform the backup.

**Question 3** Is it possible to transfer the image over to my laptop directly, without writing it to an SD-card?

Comment: That's three questions.  On StackExchange you should ask one question per post.

Comment: Q1: You need root access because Android is designed this way. Users don't have access to everything. It is the same on Linux ( here you need root or a sucker user + sudo), the only difference on Android is that on regular Android devices it is not planned that anybody gets r lot access.

Comment: "That's three questions. On StackExchange you should ask one question per post.": My question can be summarised as follows: How do I do a bitwise image of the smartphone storage and copy it to my laptop without modifying it and losing the warranty? (As far as I know, if I root the phone or unlock the bootloader, the warranty will be invalid and all user data will be wiped.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I flash Android on device with overwritten mmcblk0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218269/can-i-flash-android-on-device-with-overwritten-mmcblk0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a firmware without losing your data and restore the previous one in case it goes wrong?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219699/how-to-install-a-firmware-without-losing-your-data-and-restore-the-previous-one)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup/dump kernel image (and full ROM) without root for Mediatek Devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering data from Mi 4c able to get only to fastboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226838/recovering-data-from-mi-4c-able-to-get-only-to-fastboot)

Comment: You could always use an app such as Google One to back up your device.

Comment: @Buzzyy: Does Google One produce a bit-wise copy of the smartphone storage device(s)?

Comment: @Giorgio I'm not too sure, sorry.

Comment: only emmc/ufs storage is accessable, bitwise copy is not possible at all as apps may use [secure storage](https://source.android.com/security/keystore#architecture) (Trustonic Kinibi or Qualcomm QTEE) and so for FBE encryption keys