# How to make a really complete backup of an Android device?

Tags: linux, partitions, backup

AFAIK, all Android partitions are listed in `/dev/block/by-name`.

Assuming device encryption is turned on, if I backup all partitions with e.g. (one at a time)

```sh
for PARTITION in $(ls /dev/block/by-name)
do
    dd bs=64K if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/$PARTITION of=/partitions/$PARTITION
done
```

can I then factory reset my device, transfer the images via e.g.

```sh
for PARTITION in $(ls /partitions/partitions)
do
    dd bs=64K if=/tmp/partitions/$PARTITION of=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata
done
```

, and everything will be like before including the lockscreen encryption password? I would save the images on another device instead of `/partitions`, but let us keep it simple.

Or am I missing something?
I just want a **full** backup solution, which, after a factory reset, lets me make it as if it didn't happen. Ideally without root.

PS: I have looked into TWRP. The problem is that it only decrypts data before backup for few devices, and when it doesn't decrypt data, encryption keys are not backed up for some reason, so backups are useless for most encrypted devices.

Comment: You can't do a blockdevice backup while it is online. Even harder would be to restore it.

Comment: Modern Android devices are encrypted using a key that is derived form a key that is not exportable. Therefore dumping (encrypted) partitions is useless as you can't restore it to a different device and on the same device it may also not work if the key has been deleted.

Comment: *for foo in $(ls bar\*)* is bad scripting skills, better *for foo in bar\** and target must not fat32. much easier `adb pull`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I flash Android on device with overwritten mmcblk0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218269/can-i-flash-android-on-device-with-overwritten-mmcblk0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a firmware without losing your data and restore the previous one in case it goes wrong?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219699/how-to-install-a-firmware-without-losing-your-data-and-restore-the-previous-one)

Comment: @schklom it seems you have two different accounts (your [Super User account](https://superuser.com/users/1670025/schklom) is not linked to your [Android.SE account](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/369335/schklom)). Please refer to [the help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts and regain ownership of the question and reply to the comments on your post.